# Populating table and selecting the rows for editing with android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, tablelayout

I was having problems with populating the data in TABLE LAYOUT in android with SQLite data dynamically and after populating it I hope that the rows are selectable for editing the information in that specific row. The layout of the table that I desired was something like below.

```
    ID|name|address|phone number|
     1| Peter|NYC   |1800-900000|
     2| Parker|LAC  |1900-909090|
```

I was hoping that someone here can help me with it as I am new to android programming.

Comment: If you don't provide code its hard to figure out what you dont understand. You populate the database using `SQLiteOpenHelper` I believe. That should be an inner class to your actual class. Then using the `SQLiteDatabase` you call from within that actual class you manipulate the database. Do some research.

Comment: hi andy thanks for your reply, i notice i left out something in the questions. i was actually wondering is it possible to make a dynamic table layout for me to populate the data into the columns

Comment: Yes, You have a few options to do it with. One is `ListView`. When you go that route, I would recommend using a `CursorAdapter`, or implement it really. When you call a `ListView`'s `setAdapter()` method, you can give it all the necessary info through that. Do some quick research on that. Though it is quoted by google to avoid using `ListView` if you can do with out it. For example, if you wont be showing too much info, a TableLayout would work nicely, and its a little easier to work with in a layout.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ur planning to add table rows dynamically not the table layout as per ur comment to andy. If u want to add table rows dynamically then u can do it this way.......

```
1) Create a table Layout under ur referring xml file. 
2) Refer to that table Layout in ur java code. say "table".
3) Then create a TableRow to add it to the TableLayout.
TableRow[] row = new TableRow(this);
TextView text = new TextView(this);
name.setText(// set ur text here);
row.addView(name);
4) Now finally add that tableRow to ur table.

table.addView(row);
```

SIMILARLY U CAN ADD 'n' NO OF ROWS TO UR TABLE DYNAMICALLY.

ALL U NEED TO KNOW IS THE NO OF ENTRIES(TABLE ROWS). THEN RUN A LOOP OVER IT. WITHIN THAT LOOPING CONSTRUCT U WILL KEEP ON ADDING THE ROWS TO THE TABLE.

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestions but i have managed to solved this problem already.